# Upgrade Civicrm entire database to 5.66.0 version

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, core, directory

First time attempting to #update CiviCRM to the 5.66.0 version.  I am using #WordPress version 6.3.22 and #PHP 8.1.   If I have 68,000 individual contacts, most of them with notes in their individual profiles, groups assigned, and #hash tags assigned, how do I restore this valuable information to the updated version of CiviCRM?   I understand that I will need to remove the old Civicrm version, and all the databases from the core, clean the cache to permanently remove any old information, and upload all the contacts and their credentials.

I am new to Civicrm and platform technologies, can anyone share any information on how to restore (export) the information from the old version to the new version of Civicrm?

Thank You for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the CiviCRM community!

Where did you find instructions saying you must **delete** your CiviCRM database in order to upgrade? That's completely wrong, you definitely shouldn't do that because you will lose data!

CiviCRM upgrades are designed to be a smooth process in which you replace the old CiviCRM code with the new version, and then run the upgrade script which will automatically upgrade your database schema and clear caches for you. No data will be lost in the process, although to be extra safe you can take a snapshot of your database (using mysqldump or similar) before the upgrade.

You can find the latest upgrade instructions for CiviCRM-Wordpress here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/